# CHMOD vs UMASK - Linux file permissions

Tags: linux, chmod, systems-programming, umask

In a script, should I create a file first and then, use CHMOD to assign permissions (Example- first using TOUCH command to create a file and then, using CHMOD to edit permissions on that file) "OR" should I mask permissions using UMASK as I create a file ? Also, please explain what are the pros and cons of choosing one over another ?

Note: This file doesn't need to be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most things, it depends on far more information than you've given :-)

However, it's usually a good idea to do things in a closed manner then open them up, rather than the other way around. This is basic "Security 101".

For example, let's say you're creating a file for the user and the user has foolishly selected a `umask` of zero (effectively all files created will have full permissions for everyone).

In that case, the file is fully open for anyone to change between the creation and `chmod` stage and, while you can *minimise* this time, you cannot really remove it totally.

For the truly paranoid among us, it would be better to actually create the file in as closed a manner as possible (probably just `rw` for owner), do whatever you have to do to create the content of that file, then use `chmod` to open it up to whatever state it needs to be, something like:

```
( umask 177 ; create_file myfile.txt ; chmod 644 myfile.txt )
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly saying - it doesn't matter. And in most cases approach depends on your needing.

If you need the same file permissions over whole your script logic, I would prefer to setup it in the beginning of the script and just create file rather than create and run `chmod` command. However you can set file permissions at once at the end of script running `chmod 0XXX -R /path/to/folder`

Answer (score 0):

You should always have UMASK for specific user as you don't want to be dealing with setting permissions every-time you or an application create a file. You can further protect/release any specific files if you want using CHMOD (these cases will be very rare). Unless the file you are creating needs to be protected/accessed specifically, you should have a UMASK working for it's permissions.

- Create a separate user and specified directory for the application that is running the script.
- set it's appropriate UMASK.
- Specify extra permissions if you need it

Comment: Why can't I just use CHMOD to do this  i.e. instead of using UMASK + CHMOD, just use CHMOD? This is all done in script, so, this ain't going to be repetitive, right ?

Comment: Brother as I said, it will depend on your file whether you should use chmod or not. Regardless of that, you should always have a UMASK setup fir the user you're running that script with. You'll also need to create many other scripts and files so UMASK would only help